# Do you say "For x times" or just "x times"?

Tags: prepositions

I am wondering if it is right to say "...for [n] times or just "... [n] times" in a sentence like:

> Repeat this exercise [for] four times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat x four times.

**For is not used* with the number of times one repeats something.

You repeat an exercise once, twice, three times, four times.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat this exercise for who or what? For me? For her? For our benefit? Or for Four Times? Who is For Times? In other words, it definitely works if we assume that *Four Times* is a person's name. But generally no. *four times* is an adverbial phrase that tells you how you want the exercise to be repeated. Not for who or what, but how: four times. You don't need a preposition for that.

The only time you would use *for* in that situation is if you were saying something like this:

> Repeat this exercise **for me** four times.